# Prevent automatic tab insertion or conversion of spaces to tabs

Tags: google-docs

Google Docs has a "feature" that sometimes converts four spaces to one tab.

Copying and pasting text does not solve this problem, because the spaces in that text are converted to tabs automatically.

Is there a way to turn this off?

Comment: As a workaround, I replaced every space with a non-breaking space. That is, I replaced Unicode U+0020 with Unicode U+00A0.

Comment: Another workaround is to upload the content as a new document rather than pasting into an existing one; no conversion is applied to uploads. You can then paste from the new Google Doc into an existing one without the conversion happening.

Comment: Also here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/106582/how-do-i-prevent-google-docs-from-changing-some-spaces-to-tabs-when-pasting-fr

Answer (score 16):

No way to turn of that I know of. So annoying.

You can work-around using normal copy-paste, then a search-and-replace.

1. Copy-Paste you content into the Google Doc
2. In a text-editor, enter a tab character then cut it to your clipboard
3. Back in Google Docs, highlight the content you wish to fix
4. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open **Find and replace** dialogue
5. Paste the tab character into the **Find** field
6. Insert 4 space characters into the **Replace with** field
7. Click **Replace all**

Comment: If you're having trouble with typing a tab into the **Find** field, turn on regular expressions and use `\t`

Comment: The drivenotepad plugin acts like a standard text editor (chrome browser only)

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either... the inserted spaces are then, happily recombined into tabs... goddamn google !!!

Answer (score 7):

The approach that caused me the least headaches was to replace all spaces by another character (say underscore) in the original text, copy/paste it, then replace the underscore using find+replace. This was in Google slides.

Answer (score 3):

Click-dragging text seems to work, may depend on the OS/application though.

Get your text into an application that supports dragging selected text, e.g. another webpage with a plain textarea. Then select and drag into Google Docs.

Comment: This works and it is quick and easy

Answer (score 1):

I did find one solution: there is a Chrome plugin called "Drive Notepad" which edits google drive files and has an option "Tabs: hard"

Comment: Tried it and it seems to work. Only problem is I have to install it in every browser in every computer I use.

Answer (score 1):

i use cmd+shift+v (edit -> paste without formatting) to paste.
The spaces are not converted to tabs.

Comment: This seemed to work in some instances, but in other instances spaces are still converted. Unclear when it works and when it doesn't.

Comment: In 2023, even CTRL+SHIT+V does the (annoying) space-to-tabs conversion.